# What’s a good word for someone who doesn’t like talking about their feelings?

Tags: single-word-requests

A good adjective to describe someone who doesn’t like to talk about their feelings or confide in others.

Answer (score 4):

[Reticent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reticent)

> Not revealing one's thoughts or feelings readily.

More conversational terms could be **buttoned up**, **reserved** or even simply just **private**.

Answer (score 0):

***[Secretive:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/secretive)***

> People who are secretive hide their feelings, thoughts, intentions, and actions from other people:
>
> - *He's being very secretive about his new girlfriend.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

**reserved** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/reserved)

> 2. cool or formal in manner; restrained, silent, or reticent